# Angular parent component visibility issue

Tags: angular

I have a problem regarding routing and displaying components in Angular. So I have a login page and upon succesful login it takes me to a dashboard (The other pages can't be accessed without logging in).  My question is, is there a way of making the parent component not visible (The dashboard) when one of its children is accessed (Navigating from dashboard to a child) and if there is not, do you have any advice on how to implement this better? If you need any more details please ask me and I will tell you.

Comment: you should probably turn that child into a sibling of dashboard

Comment: Please, provide a minimal reproducible example that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Ideally, you could drop the code into a online IDE like https://stackblitz.com 
and immediately someone can get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.